# install rgdal on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgdal

I am trying to install rgdal on Ubuntu 18.04.

The error message I am having now is:

```
configure: R_HOME: /usr/lib/R
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.4-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 833
checking for gdal-config... /home/kchen/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.3.3
checking C++11 support for GDAL >= 2.3.0... yes
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... yes
checking GDAL version <= 2.5 or >= 3.0... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... no
checking gdal: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdapserver.so.7: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdapserver.so.7: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/kchen/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
/home/kchen/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_post_handshake_auth@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
/home/kchen/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
```

I did the followings before trying to install 'rgdal' in R

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade libgdal-dev
$ sudo apt-get upgrade libproj-dev
$ sudo apt-get upgrade gdal-bin
```

Not sure what else should I try. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you install them also before upgrading? With `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev gdal-bin`?

Comment: yes, i did that @SeGa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to install the dependend libraries. R also has to be >3.3.0.

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev
```

If that does not work, get sure you installed C++

```
g++: command not found
```

It is also a better solution to install the R-Packages from the console, not inside R, since every user on the machine will have access to the package then. Otherwise it will just be in your personal library.

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('rgdal', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```